# No_data_found Error when the revevant data is there

Tags: oracle10g

I'm relatively new at PL/SQL so what I'm about to ask might sound somewhat elementary. I'm trying to run the following code and getting a No_Date_Found error when I shouldn't. I'm trying to execute a loop. I'm trying to select a set of values into variables based on another variable. The highlighted  Bold line is where the error occurs. If I replace the v_tariff_code variable with a literal value in that line, the error doesn't occur anymore. Help please?

```
set serveroutput on
declare
v_remaining_arrears number := 0;
v_tariff_code date;
v_tariff_store date; --a variable that stores the value of the previous tariff while the above variable takes the next tariff code value 
v_session_start_date date; --session start date
v_con_date date; --connection date
v_start_date date;
v_c_code varchar2(10);
v_cat_code number;
vunits number;
v_w_rate number;
v_s_rate number;
v_multiples number;
v_session_current varchar2(20);
v_counter number;
v_date1 date;
v_date2 date;


begin
v_c_code := 'D2203447'; 
v_session_current := 'JAN2014-FEB2014';
--V_SESSION_START_DATE := '01-JAN-14';
--v_date1 := v_session_start_date; --v_date1 would always begin as the session start date
--select v_session_start_date into v_date1 from dual;
--loop
select cat_code, units, con_date into v_cat_code, vunits, v_con_date from consumer where c_code = v_c_code;
    select start_date into v_session_start_date from bill_session where session_code = v_session_current;


v_start_date := v_session_start_date;

loop
v_start_date := v_start_date - 30;

select MAX(tariff_code) INTO v_TARIFF_CODE from tariff where tariff_code < V_START_DATE;

**select w_rate, s_rate into v_w_rate, v_s_rate from cat_tariff where cat_code = v_cat_code and 
tariff_code = v_tariff_code;** 



v_remaining_arrears := v_remaining_arrears + ((round(v_w_rate *v_multiples*vunits) + round(v_s_rate * vunits)));

exit when v_start_date < v_con_date;


--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ARREARS = ' || V_REMAINING_ARREARS);

end loop;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ARREARS = ' || V_REMAINING_ARREARS);

end;
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
select w_rate, s_rate 
into v_w_rate, v_s_rate 
from cat_tariff 
where cat_code = v_cat_code and tariff_code = v_tariff_code;
```

This is an exact fetch which must return exactly one record. Is query returns zero or more then one records it causes the exception.

Try to add `dbms_output.put_line(v_cat_code || ',' || v_tariff_code);` before the query. Exactly before the exception this line will show problem values of `v_cat_code` and `v_tariff_code`.

Probable you wolud like to ignore this exception and process only cases which definitely return data. In this case you shold use `BEGIN … EXCEPTION … END`

```
begin
  select w_rate, s_rate 
  into v_w_rate, v_s_rate 
  from cat_tariff 
  where cat_code = v_cat_code and tariff_code = v_tariff_code;
  -- DO SOMETHING USEFULL WITH v_w_rate, v_s_rate 
exception
  when no_data_found then null;
  when others then raise;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I added the line dbms_output.put_line(v_cat_code || ',' || v_tariff_code); before the query but I'm getting the same error. The query is in fact an exact fetch and I get no errors if I replace v_tariff_code with a literal value. The value of v_tariff_code is supposed to be select MAX(tariff_code) INTO v_TARIFF_CODE from tariff where tariff_code < v_start_date; This query fetches exactly one value into v_tariff_code –

If you could suggest something else, I'd be mighty grateful

Comment: Yes right, you will get the same error because of data. Look at last values shown by this command, and try to manually perform the query with substituting these values instead of variables (and withot INTO clause). If it returns 0 rows this is the values which generated exception.

Comment: Your literal value and value of v_tariff_code  are different. DBMS_OUTPUT can help you to see its real value during execution.

Comment: I made a little progress. I found out that if I remove the loop, the error no longer occurs and I do get an output. This means my query is correct but maybe the loop is altering the variable somehow? Any ideas?

Comment: I made some more progress. Your suggestion was really helpful. I displayed the various variable values with and without the loop and apparently, the loop is messing with the value of the v_session_start_date which in turn returns a null value to the v_tariff_code variable. And that returns a no_data_found error at the end. Any ideas on how to fix this? I mean all I'm doing is a simple arithmetic operation on the v_session_start_date value. Why is it being so erratic within the loop?

Comment: I think I've finally figured it out. The database doesn't differentiate between 01-JAN-2001 AND 01-JAN-1901 when they come up like 01-JAN-01 and 01-JAN-01 respectively. Know what I mean...?? ;)

Comment: It does. '01-JAN-50' → 01.01.1959 but '01-JAN-49' → 01.01.2049.
Additionally learn more about [Datetime literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51049)